# Is it worth coding for users who may not have JavaScript enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How safe is it to assume that most users will have JS enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485890/how-safe-is-it-to-assume-that-most-users-will-have-js-enabled)
>   [Is it reasonable to assume my visitors have javascript enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155615/is-it-reasonable-to-assume-my-visitors-have-javascript-enabled)

I'm worrying about this and don't know if I should be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485890/how-safe-is-it-to-assume-that-most-users-will-have-js-enabled-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155615/is-it-reasonable-to-assume-my-visitors-have-javascript-enabled

Comment: This completely depends on your market, your resources, and your application design. If you're setting out to do a really rich application, then keeping a non-JS site working essentially means maintaining a parallel application with its own, pure HTML design. That's a fine and noble thing to do, but again whether it makes any sense depends on *your* user community.

Answer (score 5):

To cope with that, it is worth reading:

- [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)
- [Graceful degradation](http://webtips.dan.info/graceful.html)

Answer (score 3):

To target the maximum amount of users you really want your site to have some functionality available when JavaScript is disabled. Now if this is some corporate intranet application then it is a different story because your IT department will be able to make sure their PCs are configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Is SEO important to your site because Crawlers can't access any content that requires Javascript.  So if you want your site to perform well in google, etc. searches then make sure it works without javascript.  Otherwise, just consider your target audience and make a decision that way.

Also search for "unobtrusive javascript" on google, lots of hints / tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be considered. At a minimum there should be a message on the page stating that Javascript is required for a particular element to function.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) 5% of users don't have JavaScript enabled. So, the solution would be using JavaScript and also keeping that 5% in mind and providing additional information to them such as asking them to enable the feature or providing service using another approach.

Comment: 5% sounds small.  To put it in another context - that's 1 out of every 20 visitors to your site.

Comment: No, it doesn't *necessarily* mean that 1 in 20 visitors to *his* website will have Javascript disabled. For example, an application designed for a corporate intranet is a totally different thing than a public shopping site.

Comment: Yeah I guess Google has the most accurate stats.