# Will Richfaces components work if javascript is disabled

Tags: richfaces

I am using RichFaces ajax components in my application. For example `<rich:dropDownMenu >`, `<rich:suggestion >`  etc .  But these will not work if I disable the javascript in browser. 
Is there any way through which we can make Richfaces work even if javascript has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write JavaScript if you use RichFaces, but Richfaces needs JavaScript.
Modern rich web applications require JavaScript, dynamic behavior is driven by JavaScript. Also see:
[Is it reasonable to assume my visitors have javascript enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155615/is-it-reasonable-to-assume-my-visitors-have-javascript-enabled)

Comment: Yea right , Richfaces comes with lot of Javascript and Jquery built in. So the only way is I assume that users of the site have javascript enabled.

Comment: You can show a warning to the users in case it is disabled with the noscript tag